# Get return address of a function using kretprobe or bpf

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, kprobe

Is it possible to identify where the kernel function returned using `kretprobe` or `BPF` code? For example;

```
void func()
{
.........some line......
.........some line......
  if (condition1)
    return;
.........some line......
.........some line......
  if(condition2)
     return;
.........some line......
  if(condition3)
     return;
.........some line......
.........some line......
.........some line......
  return;
}
```

If I have a kernel function like this, how would I know which return was hit?

Comment: The compiler will re-write your function to `void foo() { return; }`. There isn't much to check. Now it would be another story had you made the function non-void and returned different values in each branch.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I have edited the code to avoid confusion. This code is to elaborate my question not the real one. Generally I would like to know how to get to know at what statement the function returned using kprobe/bpf .

Comment: You could kprobe on each return line. There is nothing in CPU instruction execution that remembers the past instruction path.

Comment: @stark, you meant use the address of instruction and keep the probe there, like 'p:0x012345H' ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create a kprobe on each return line.

If you are the author of the function you try to trace, I'd just set a global variable to certain value for each branch taken.